# Integrate linkedin sdk and android studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk, linkedin-api, build.gradle

I'm trying to integrate the sdk of linkedin into an existing android studio project, but i could not understand how to do it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and the related "on-topic" page.  Generally speaking, the community wants to see posts that show your work so its easier to tell you why its breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can start integrating the SDK, which can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android. This SDK contains the Java libraries that do the heavy lifting of OAuth as well as the REST calls for each social provider. Extract the contents and we are all set.

Copy the libs/socialauth-android-2.5.jar and libs/socialauth4.2 jar into the libs folder of your application. If you have the latest Android Development Tools (ADT), jars will be automatically added to your build path. If not, you will need to manually add the jar files in build path. We recommend you upgrade to the latest ADT.
Copy the assets/oauth_consumer.properties file to the assets folder of your application. The file is used by the SDK for the API and secret keys. Replace the default entries with the keys generated by following the above steps.
Add  android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in manifest.
That is all you need to get started. The SDK .zip file also contains code samples which can help you go ahead with the coding.

Please see this link : [enter link description here](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-2-using-socialauth-to-integrate-linkedin-api-in-android)